# How do I determine if a point (X, Y, Z) is inside a FamilyInstance?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I want to determine if a point (X, Y, Z) is inside a FamilyInstance by Revit-Api?

Is it possible to achieve this?[image]

I have previously used **`get_BoundingBox`** to determine the position based on the maximum and minimum points. However, it produces incorrect results when the **`familyinstance`** is skewed. Therefore, I would like to know if there are alternative methods or APIs to achieve this.

[image: On this beam, there shouldn't be any casing . However, due to the inclination, my algorithm incorrectly identifies the casing on the adjacent beam as being within the bounding box of the selected beam]

On this beam, there shouldn't be any casing . However, due to the inclination, my algorithm incorrectly identifies the casing on the adjacent beam as being within the bounding box of the selected beam

Comment: can you give more context to where this point is coming from? or why do you need to do it like this ? maybe there is different approach that will be more easier

Comment: There is a Filter in the `RevitAPIDocs` called  BoundingBoxContainsPointFilter , find it through this link https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/a5ea9f5a-ddba-9db7-eaa0-2b37098f0142.htm

Comment: I want to embed pipes onto beams using the information provided in https://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/3afcdf82-b25c-3092-d42c-b60490075d22.htm. I currently have several sets of data regarding the positions and dimensions of beams and pipes (obtained from AutoCAD annotations). First, I need to confirm which pipe is within which beam. Therefore, I need to determine if the pipe's position is within the already generated beam (NewFamilyInstance).

Comment: So basically, you still don't have the 3D of the elements, you are working on the data obtained from Autocad only?

Comment: but according to the new image you added, you have 3D Elements , why not use an `IntersectionFilter` like `ElementIntersectsElementFilter` in Revit using the Revit API, to determine which pipe intersects with  which beam.

Comment: I have 3D elements for beams, but they don't have sleeves yet. I want to determine which beam the casing should be on based on sleeve information in CAD. After that, I intend to use the information provided in https://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/3afcdf82-b25c-3092-d42c-b60490075d22.htm to draw the casing on the beams.

I apologize. I meant to say casing instead of pipes.

Comment: so to sum up, you only have the Beams, but no 3D pipes ?

Comment: Yes, my goal is to add sleeves to 3D elements (beams) based on the data from CAD.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to determine the geometric extents of the instance. The bounding box is larger than the extents and con give false positives, just as you say. More precise geometry can be obtained querying the instnace for its geometrical representation using the [`Geometry` property](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/d8a55a5b-2a69-d5ab-3e1f-6cf1ee43c8ec.htm). Once you have the geometric extents, you need a method to check whether the point is inside or out. You are apparently already handling this for the bounding box. One way to obtain a simplified representation of the geometric extents that also is somewhat larger than the exact exact geometry but may solve the skewed problem that you refer to would be to calculate the convex hull from the geometry vertices:

- [Convex Hull and Volume Computation](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/06/convex-hull-and-volume-computation.html)
- [Online Revit API Docs and Convex Hull](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/08/online-revit-api-docs-and-convex-hull.html)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, and another possibility: if your family instance is roughly bounded by a  right-angle cuboid or hexahedron, so the bounding box would be a sensible fit except for the skewed position: in that case, you could simply add a transformation to the bounding box, and the article on [Bounding Boxes Axis Alignment and Transformation](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2023/07/bounding-boxes-axis-alignment-and-transformation.html) might come in handy.